# Populating ListFragment from String resource crashes

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

I'm trying to populate my ListFragment from a String resource but I'm having some problems.

My app crashes with the error `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment Fragment2{45f6f8d0} not attached to Activity` and I'm not sure why.

It works when I populate my ListFragment with local Strings from the class but not when I try to use "R.string.resource"

How would I be able to achieve this by referencing my strings to the R.string.resorce?

```
public class Fragment2 extends SherlockListFragment {

public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context myContext;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        myContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.month);
        label.setText(month[position]);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);


        icon.setImageResource(drawables[position]);

        return row;
    }

}

int[] drawables = { R.drawable.abstract_icon, R.drawable.animal_icon,
        R.drawable.anime_icon, R.drawable.buildings_icon,
        R.drawable.icon_cars, R.drawable.cartoon_icon,
        R.drawable.icon_city, R.drawable.colorful_icon,
        R.drawable.icon_fantasy, R.drawable.flower_iconm,
        R.drawable.icon_food, R.drawable.icon_girly,
        R.drawable.nature_icon, R.drawable.nightscape_icon,
        R.drawable.paintings_icon, R.drawable.patters_icon,
        R.drawable.portrait, R.drawable.rain_icon, R.drawable.sea_icon,
        R.drawable.space_icon, R.drawable.trees_icon,
        R.drawable.vibrant_icon

};

    //Here

String[] month = { getString(R.string.abstarct),
        getString(R.string.animal), getString(R.string.anime),
        getString(R.string.buildings), getString(R.string.cars),
        getString(R.string.cartoon), getString(R.string.city),
        getString(R.string.colorful), getString(R.string.fantasy),
        getString(R.string.flowers), getString(R.string.food),
        getString(R.string.girly), getString(R.string.nature),
        getString(R.string.nightscape), getString(R.string.paintings),
        getString(R.string.patterns), getString(R.string.portrait),
        getResources().getString(R.string.rain), getString(R.string.sea),
        getString(R.string.space), getString(R.string.trees),
        getString(R.string.vibrant) };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    MyListAdapter myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.row, month);
    setListAdapter(myListAdapter);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.category, container, false);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the `Context` resources at the time of intializing `Fragmnet`...

`Context` resources can be accessed from  `Fragment` from the `onAttach()` callback through which you will get `Activity` reference

so initialize your `month` String array in `onAttach()`

```
    private String[] month;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        month = new String[]{ getString(R.string.abstarct),
                getString(R.string.animal), getString(R.string.anime),
                getString(R.string.buildings), getString(R.string.cars),
                getString(R.string.cartoon), getString(R.string.city),
                getString(R.string.colorful), getString(R.string.fantasy),
                getString(R.string.flowers), getString(R.string.food),
                getString(R.string.girly), getString(R.string.nature),
                getString(R.string.nightscape), getString(R.string.paintings),
                getString(R.string.patterns), getString(R.string.portrait),
                getResources().getString(R.string.rain), getString(R.string.sea),
                getString(R.string.space), getString(R.string.trees),
                getString(R.string.vibrant) };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change month to an `int` array, which only contains the resource ids, and use

```
label.setText(myContext.getString(month[position]));
```